# Create N tasks in step function. One for each lambda function that exists in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I'm just trying to create a simple step function where each task runs sequentially:
`task1 -> task2 -> task3`

One task for every lambda in `lambda_handler_paths` = `['/Users/aaronwest/Code/ce-engineering-test-live/tests/tf-senior-engineer/validators/my-other-function/lambda.zip', '/Users/aaronwest/Code/ce-engineering-test-live/tests/tf-senior-engineer/validators/my-function/lambda.zip']`

Here's what I been playing with to try and get something working:

```
def build_state_machine_definition(validators: list) -> dict:
    """Builds a state machine definition for a given list of tests"""

    # Create initial state
    definition = sfn.Chain.start(state=sfn.Pass(self, "Pass"))

    # Loop over tests and add to state machine definition
    for i, validator in enumerate(validators):
        # Get the name of the  lambda function
        lambda_name = validator.split("/")[-2]
        print("lambda_name: " + str(lambda_name))
        lambda_function = _lambda.Function(
            self,
            f"{lambda_name}-lambda",
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset(validator),
            handler="lambda_function.lambda_handler",
            timeout=Duration.seconds(30),
        )

        if i == len(validators) - 1:
            # This is the last LambdaInvoke task
            definition.next(
                tasks.LambdaInvoke(
                    self, f"{lambda_name}-Validation", lambda_function=lambda_function
                )
            )
        else:
            definition.next(
                tasks.LambdaInvoke(
                    self, f"{lambda_name}-Validate", lambda_function=lambda_function
                )
            )

    return definition


state_machine_definition = build_state_machine_definition(lambda_handler_paths)

# Create a single Step Function
sfn.StateMachine(
    self,
    "StateMachine",
    definition=state_machine_definition,
    timeout=Duration.minutes(10),
)
```

at the moment I'm receiving `RuntimeError: Error: State 'Pass' already has a next state`

Comment: the `definition` prop of `StateMachine` expects an `IChainable`, but you're passing a string.

Comment: originally I was using `definition = sfn.Chain.start(state=sfn.Succeed(self, "Succeeded"))` but I was also having a lot of issue with it, so I was trying to just use a json definition

Comment: You will have to pass the type it expects. Not sure I understand this code snippet, though, as it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Okay, I have edited my code snippet to reflect what I have spent most of my time trying to get working. Basically, I have a `lambda_handler_paths` that is equal to n number of lambda handler file paths. for each item in that list, I need a task added to the step function.

Comment: The expected result is to have a step function with a lambda invoke task for each lambda in `lambda_handler_paths`

Comment: The issue is that the `next()` function returns a chainable - it does not modify the original `definition` cariable. You could reassign to the same variable with `definition = definition.next(...)`

Comment: @gshpychka that was the solution! It worked great. Modifying the orig value is all that was needed. I’ll mark as the correct answer if you post it. And thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `next()` function on an `IChainable` does not modify the object, but instead returns a new one that would contain the new chain. This means that you need to store the results of these calls in a variable:

```
definition = definition.next(...)
```

instead of

```
definition.next(...)
```